# Как в public static final String ADMIN_PANEL_URL= получить значение (R.string.domin_url)

Tags: java, android

Могу ли я назначить  `public static final String ADMIN_PANEL_URL` значение из `(R.string.domin_url)`?
При этом я пытаюсь при переключении языка в приложении `String ADMIN_PANEL_URL` ссылался на значение из `value/strings.xml(en)` и `value/strings.xml(ru)` при условии что в каждом `value/strings.xml`находится разный текст для `string name="domin_url"` , возможно ли это ?

Так получаю значение из `public static final String ADMIN_PANEL_URL="https://myDomain.com"`

```
 private static final String BASE_URL = Config.ADMIN_PANEL_URL;
 public static final String GET_RECENT_PRODUCT = BASE_URL + "/api/api.php? 
 get_recent";
 public static final String GET_PRODUCT_ID = BASE_URL + "/api/api.php? 
 product_id=";
```

Это класс где вывожу

```
`public class FragmentRecent extends Fragment implements RecyclerAdapterProduct.ContactsAdapterListener { 
.......
    private void fetchData() {
            JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(GET_RECENT_PRODUCT, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            if (response == null) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.failed_fetch_data), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                return;
                            }

                            List<Product> items = new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), new TypeToken<List<Product>>() {
                            }.getType());

                            // adding contacts to contacts list
                            productList.clear();
                            productList.addAll(items);

                            // refreshing recycler view
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // error in getting json
                    Log.e("INFO", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            });

            MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
        }`
```

Comment: Почему Вы не пробуете это сделать? По-моему, это будет быстрее чем писать вопрос и ждать ответов.

Comment: @V.March- Я пробовал уже , переводит строку в int и выдаёт идентификатор строки вместо самой строки. Я просто подумал что возможно я в чём то ошибаюсь , поэтому и создал такой вопрос.

Comment: Можете привести код в котором получаете значение из src и сэтите в переменную? А то что-то порядок  действий теряется.

Comment: Подозреваю что просто некорректно получаете значение.

Comment: @V.March - я отредактировал вопрос и добавил инфы..

Comment: Значение со стринга для переменной `ADMIN_PANEL_URL` Вы видимо получаете в классе `Config`. Там же его и сэтите. А в приведенном классе я вижу уже обработку ответа с ретрофита - не вижу связи. Объясните на каком этапе у Вас получается интовое значение вместо стрингового в переменной `ADMIN_PANEL_URL`. И как вы об этом узнаете.

Comment: Я так понимаю что Вы хотите менять урл сервера в зависимости от локали которую выбрал пользователь. И при смене языка(локали)обновлять контент с целевого сервера. Верно?

Comment: значение можно получить только от контекста.. с другой стороны нет смысла хранить это значение, оно и так, наверное можно сказать, статическое, только лежит в другом месте.. к тому же, если оно вдруг все же вычислится для одного языка, какие гарантии, что класс убьется при переключении на другой язык и не останется старое значение.. нет смысла городить неопределенность

Comment: @V.March - Всё верно , хочу обновлять контент при смене локали. Вот на этом этапе получаю интовое значение ` public static final String ADMIN_PANEL_URL = (R.string.domin);`

Comment: @V.March - Пробовал и так `public static final String ADMIN_PANEL_URL = getString(R.string.domin);   private static String getString(int domin) {
        
    }`

Comment: Видимо Вы как раз и получаете с помощью `(R.string.domin)` интовую ССЫЛКУ на  ресурс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал так. Когда пользователь выбирает конкретный язык, то просто перезапускать ретрофит запрос и обновлять контент.

А так сэтить Вашу строку с ресурсов.

```
private static final String BASE_URL = getResources().getString(R.string.domin);
```

Comment: У вас есть пример перезапуска ретрофит запроса что бы обновлять контент?

Comment: @Shihzamanapp А как Вы делаете запрос на контент изначально?  Вот это же повторите.

Comment: Значит я должен сначала отловить смену языка и если язык en то обновить?

Comment: @Shihzamanapp Я бы так сделал, но это вероятно не единственный способ.